# Can I declare an HTML5 video, with both VP8 and VP9 source?

Tags: html5-video, webm

I'd like to source both VP8 and VP9 versions of a webm video, along with mp4 as third option, due to the fact somme browsers don't support VP9 but do support VP8. Is this possible?

I was thinking of using the following code:

```
<video autoplay loop muted poster="/images/myvideoimage.jpg">
  <source src="myvideo-vp9.webm" type='video/webm;codecs="vp9, vorbis"'/>
  <source src="myvideo-vp8.webm" type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"'/>
  <source src="myvideo.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
  <img src="/images/myvideoimage.jpg"/>
</video>
```

My question is, will the browser determine that it can't handle VP9, and use VP8 if it can do so?

I've search extensively online for info about this, but didn't find anything.

Thank you,

Jonathan

Comment: the best you're going to get to check up-front is canPlayType - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canPlayType - but it's not great. You may have to test and fall back manually

Comment: Thanks. So is it the case then that browsers don't actually read the codec data declared in the video tag, and/or don't move to the next source if they the browser doesn't support that codec?